# Proving $[L_i,R_j] = i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}R_{k}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, commutator

I need to prove $[L_i,R_j] = i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}R_{k}$.

I have that $L_i = \epsilon_{ijk}R_{j}P_{k}$ , so the commutator becomes:

$$[\epsilon_{ijk}R_{j}P_{k},R_{j}] = \epsilon_{ijk}\left(R_j[P_k,R_j]+[R_j,R_j]P_k\right).$$

I know $[R_j,R_j] = 0$  but I'm unsure about the other commutator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just help with the position momentum commutator, let's rewrite it in position representation. 
$[r_i, p_j] =[r_i,-i\hbar\partial _{r_j}] =r_ip_j-(-i\hbar r_i\partial _{r_j} - i\hbar \delta_{ij}) = i\hbar \delta_{ij} $ I used Leibniz rule for the second part of the commutator.

Comment: So then I would get $\epsilon_{ijk}R_{j}(-i\hbar\delta_{kj})$

Comment: And you can use the delta on the sum of j, you should probably write a different index for the second r in your commutator because the first j is a summed over

Comment: So then would I get $ [L_i,R_l] = -i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}R_j \delta_{kl} $

Comment: The double k means it's summed over k which makes it $\epsilon_{ijl} $ which equals $-\epsilon_{ilj} $